# Signed 16-bit ALSA PCM data to U8 Conversion on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, audio, alsa

I'm attempting to convert 16-bit ALSA PCM Samples to Unsigned 8-bit PCM samples for wireless transmission on Linux. The receiving machine is playing the transmitted data successfully and the recorded voice is there and recognizable, but the quality is terrible and noisy. I've tried ALSA mixer on both ends to tune the stream but it doesn't seem to get much better with that. I believe there is something wrong with my conversion of the samples to 8-bit PCM but its just a simple shift so I'm not sure what could be the error. Does anyone have any suggestions or see anything wrong with my conversion code? Thanks.

Conversion Code:

```
            // This byte array needs to be the packet size we wish to send
            QByteArray prepareToSend;
            prepareToSend.clear();

            // Keep reading from ALSA until we fill one full frame
            int frames = 1;
            while ( prepareToSend.size() < TARGET_TX_BUFFER_SIZE ) {

                // Create a ByteArray
                QByteArray readBytes;
                readBytes.resize(size);

                // Read with ALSA
                short sample[1]; // Data is signed 16-bit
                int rc = snd_pcm_readi(m_PlaybackHandle, sample, frames);
                if (rc == -EPIPE) {
                    /* EPIPE means overrun */
                    fprintf(stderr, "Overrun occurred\n");
                    snd_pcm_prepare(m_PlaybackHandle);
                } else if (rc < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            "Error from read: %s\n",
                            snd_strerror(rc));
                } else if (rc != (int)frames) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Short read, read %d frames\n", rc);
                }
                else {
                    // Copy bytes to the prepare to send buffer
                    //qDebug() << "Bytes for sample buffer: " << sizeof(sample);
                    prepareToSend.append((qint16)(sample[0]) >> 8); // signed 16-bit becomes u8
                }

            }
```

ALSA Configuration:

```
        // Setup parameters
        int size;
        snd_pcm_t *m_PlaybackHandle;
        snd_pcm_hw_params_t *m_HwParams;
        char *buffer;

        qDebug() << "Desire to Transmit Data - Setting up ALSA Now....";

        // Error handling
        int err;

        // Device to Write to
        const char *snd_device_in = "hw:1,0";

        if ((err = snd_pcm_open (&m_PlaybackHandle, snd_device_in, SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open audio device %s (%s)\n",
                     snd_device_in,
                     snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
        snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&m_HwParams);

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc (&m_HwParams)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot allocate hardware parameter structure (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any (m_PlaybackHandle, m_HwParams)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot initialize hardware parameter structure (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access (m_PlaybackHandle, m_HwParams, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot set access type (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(m_PlaybackHandle, m_HwParams, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16)) < 0) { // Has to be 16 bit
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot set sample format (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);

        }

        uint sample_rate = 8000;
        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate (m_PlaybackHandle, m_HwParams, sample_rate, 0)) < 0) { // 8 KHz
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot set sample rate (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels (m_PlaybackHandle, m_HwParams, 1)) < 0) { // 1 Channel Mono
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot set channel count (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        /*
        Frames: samples x channels (i.e: stereo frames are composed of two samples, mono frames are composed of 1 sample,...)
        Period: Number of samples tranferred after which the device acknowledges the transfer to the apllication (usually via an interrupt).
        */

        /* Submit params to device */
        if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params(m_PlaybackHandle, m_HwParams)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot set parameters (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        /* Free the Struct */
        snd_pcm_hw_params_free(m_HwParams);

        // Flush handle prepare for record
        snd_pcm_drop(m_PlaybackHandle);

        if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (m_PlaybackHandle)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot prepare audio interface for use (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }

        qDebug() << "Done Setting up ALSA....";

        // Prepare the device
        if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (m_PlaybackHandle)) < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "cannot prepare audio interface for use (%s)\n",
                     snd_strerror (err));
            exit (1);
        }
```

Comment: 8000 sample rate sounds pretry low... Are you sure you do not hear exactly what you are supposed to with that sample rate?

Comment: Yes, I've tried the same thing with PulseAudio on the sending side with the same framerate and it sounds very clear. Not noisy at all. I also turned off resampling in the PulseAudio config. This is running on a small embedded Linux device though so PulseAudio caused a long ( 10 second ) delay in getting the data. I'm sure it was doing filtering but no remixing.

Comment: the shift of the data by 8 bits to the right will eliminate almost all the detail of the sound.  suggest using some kind of compression algorithm to resolve 16 bits into 8 bits.  perhaps by taking pairs of bits from the 16 bits, using a majority rule and in ties, a use high order bit rule to compress the data to 8 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(qint16)(sample[0]) >> 8` will convert signed linear 16-bit PCM to signed linear 8-bit PCM.  If you want unsigned linear 8-bit then it would be `((quint16)sample[0] ^ 0x8000) >> 8`.

Although 16-bit PCM is almost always on a linear scale, 8-bit PCM is more commonly on a log scale (either µ-law or A-law), and a lookup table is usually used for conversion.  If you really do want linear 8-bit then you may want to first adjust the gain so that the peak is at 0 dBFS and use audio compression to reduce the dynamic range so that it will fit in 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `plughw:1,0` instead of `hw:1,0`, you can just tell the device that you want `SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8`, and the samples will be converted automatically.
(This works also for µ-Law and A-Law.)